# I want to play audio file from Google Drive in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, google-drive-api

I want to play audio files that are present on my Google Drive. How can I do that in Flutter?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to first download the audio files from Google Drive and then play them using a Flutter audio player package.

- First use the Google Drive API to authenticate and access files from
  your Google Drive account.

  ```
  Future<String> _downloadFile(String url, String fileName) async {
       final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
       final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
       final filePath = '${directory.path}/$fileName';
       final file = File(filePath);
       await file.writeAsBytes(response.bodyBytes);
       return filePath;
     }
  ```
- Use a Flutter audio player package to play the downloaded audio
  files.

  ```
  Future<void> _playAudio() async {
   if (_isPlaying) {
     await _audioPlayer.stop();
     setState(() => _isPlaying = false);
   } else {
     final filePath = await _downloadFile(widget.audioUrl, 'audio.mp3');
     await _audioPlayer.play(filePath, isLocal: true);
     setState(() => _isPlaying = true);
   }
  ```

  }

Comment: what if i have the URL of the file that is present on a drive In that case we need to set up for drive authentication. if yes then is there any other way so I can access it directly from the URL?